# PHPStan reporting "extends unknown class" for a core CakePHP feature

Tags: cakephp, phpstan

I have a web application which is running on CakePHP 4.4.4

I have recently started using PHPStan with the codebase running at [level 1](https://phpstan.org/user-guide/rule-levels). This level is specified in our configuration file, `phpstan.neon`

After generating a [baseline](https://phpstan.org/user-guide/baseline) with

```
vendor/bin/phpstan analyse --configuration phpstan.neon src/ tests/ --generate-baseline
```

this added approx 80 errors to `phpstan-baseline.neon`. There was a message saying some errors couldn't be baselined and the advice was to re-run PHPStan.

On running `vendor/bin/phpstan analyse src/ --memory-limit=1G` it reported 6 errors about a CakePHP class which is being used in a few different files inside `src/Command/`. One such example is:

> Class `App\Command\AlertsCommand` extends unknown class `Cake\Console\Command`.

If I open the file it's referring to, `src/Command/AlertsCommand.php`, we have this:

```
<?php
namespace App\Command;

use Cake\Console\Command;

class AlertsCommand extends Command
{
    public function initialize(): void
    {
        parent::initialize();
        // ...
    }
 
    // Other functions for this command defined here onwards

}
```

VSCode red-underlines "Command" (as in `extends Command`) and a tooltip says

> Undefined type 'Cake\Console\Command'

When referring to the CakePHP 4 docs here https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/console-commands/commands.html I noticed it has `use Cake\Command\Command;` as opposed to `use Cake\Console\Command;`. I updated this and re-ran PHPStan.

The number of errors increased from 6 to 7 with a message specifically about this change which said:

> Ignored error pattern #^App\Command\AlertsCommand::initialize() calls parent::initialize() but App\Command\AlertsCommand does not extend any class.$# in path src/Command/AlertsCommand.php was not matched in reported errors.

This doesn't make any sense. It says - quote - "AlertsCommand does not extend any class" but clearly it does:

```
class AlertsCommand **extends Command**
```

The application itself works so none of the original code - before making the `use` modification - is stopping anything from working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHPStan tells you:

> Ignored error pattern … was not matched in reported errors.

This means you’re ignoring something that’s no longer happening. You can just remove this ignored error from config/baseline.

You can also set `reportUnmatchedIgnoredErrors: false` and this is not going to be reported. See the documentation: https://phpstan.org/user-guide/ignoring-errors#reporting-unused-ignores